# Splitting a string from a character

Tags: c++, string, split

I was trying to make a program that would split a string into a 2D array `token[100][100]`. It would split the whole string into separate words but every time it comes across a period it should `token[i++][j]`. So far I have this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <istream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string code;
    getline(cin, code);
    string codef[100];
    string token[100][100];
    int j = 0, i=0;
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        stringstream ssin(code);
        while (ssin.good() && j < 4) {
            ssin >> token[i][j];
            ++j;
            if (token[i][j] == ".") {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            cout << token[i][j] << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The way I have done it requires you to put a space before the period because, it checks for separate strings and if you bunch the period like so: "hello." it won't recognize it apparently. I don't want that to happen, is there a better way of making this work? Right now I limited the string to have only 2 sentences and 4 words per sentence including the period so technically only 3 words then a period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply use [std::string::find_first_of](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of) to search for your delimiters on a plain vanilla std::string? It will return [std::string::npos](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/npos) when nothing is found. Btw: I really would suggest to drop that good old array stuff for std::array or std::vector. Using std::vector would get you rid of those crappy hardcoded limits.

Anyway, here is what I would suggest. Note: I left out limit checking for the array access to have the code easier to read for you, either you migrate to vector and use push_back or you have to **add limit checks**.

I think the code is pretty much self-explanatory, just one remark: the `if(pos > last_pos)` is needed because `pos == last_pos` when we don´t find another delimiter.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string code = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. Lorem ipsum dolor. Cooky";

    std::string token[100][100];
    std::size_t last_pos = 0, pos;
    int sentence = 0, word = 0;
    while ((pos = code.find_first_of(". ", last_pos)) != std::string::npos)
    {
        if (pos > last_pos)
            token[sentence][word] = code.substr(last_pos, pos-last_pos /*length*/ );

        if(code.substr(pos, 1)[0] == '.')
        {
            ++sentence;
            word = 0;
        }
        else
            ++word;
        last_pos = pos+1;
    }
    if (last_pos < code.length())
        token[sentence][word] = code.substr(last_pos, std::string::npos);


    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            std::cout << token[i][j] << std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is a little bit obscured, because of your hardcoded limits, but that has nothing to do with the string splitting so I left it as it is:

```
The
quick
brown
fox


Lorem
ipsum
dolor


Cooky
```